# How do you log out from this site?

Tags: discussion

Sorry for asking this question but I don't know how to log out from this site, I did look for answer in help section but couldn't find it, I am new here.

Comment: This could be done by showing efforts, but this one shows no efforts.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the icon of stack exchange discussion, it will open a popup there you can see a label on the right of the popup. See below for the image.

[image]